# Ebean.delete() creates wrong SQL for many-to-many relation

Tags: jpa, orm, many-to-many, ebean

I have two simple Entities *Issue* and *Tag*, and a `many-to-many` relation between them. Everything works find except when I want to delete an *Issue* using `Ebean.delete(Issue.class, id)` which results in this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Unknown column
 'issue_id' in 'where clause' 
Bind values:[1b7e5955c26b51dex546fca27x13cc54c2531x-7fef, ] 
Query was:
select t0.id c0 
from tag t0 
where issue_id=?
```

The very strange thing is, that obviously the **generated SQL is wrong**. It tries to access an `issue_id` in the `tag` table but there is none. I hope this in no bug in Ebean but just a mistake of mine, but I have no idea what it could be.

Here are the entity beans (I removed the getters/setters) and the DDL generated by Ebean:

**Issue Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Issue {

    @Id @Column(length=64)
    private String id;    // <-- I use assigned ids
    @Version
    private Date timeStamp;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String createdBy;
    @CreatedTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    private String state;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name="issue_tag",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="issue_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

**Tag Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id @Column(length=64)
    private String id;    // <-- I use assigned ids
    @Version
    private Date timeStamp;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Issue> issues;
}
```

**Generated DDL**

```
create table issue (
  id                        varchar(64) not null,
  title                     varchar(255),
  description               varchar(255),
  created_by                varchar(255),
  state                     varchar(255),
  time_stamp                datetime not null,
  created_at                datetime not null,
  constraint pk_issue primary key (id))
;

create table tag (
  id                        varchar(64) not null,
  name                      varchar(255),
  time_stamp                datetime not null,
  constraint pk_tag primary key (id))
;

create table issue_tag (
  issue_id                       varchar(64) not null,
  tag_id                         varchar(64) not null,
  constraint pk_issue_tag primary key (issue_id, tag_id))
;

alter table issue_tag add constraint fk_issue_tag_issue_01 foreign key (issue_id) references issue (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;

alter table issue_tag add constraint fk_issue_tag_tag_02 foreign key (tag_id) references tag (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

Comment: What implementation of JPA are you using? Does yours require you to implement Serializable or provider a getter for id?

Comment: @user1888440 I'm using Ebean ORM as mentioned above. And everything else (create, update) works fine, it's just the delete that goes wrong. Meanwhile I posted the question to their Google Group too and it seems that it's a bug in Ebean.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you set delete cascades on `many-to-many` relations. Cascading of delete operation should be done carefully. It should only be set on `one` side of `one-to-one` or `one-to-many`.

Deletion should be cascaded only to objects that cannot exist separately. So if we have class `Person` we can set delete cascade on list of addresses or on relation to class with additional info. 
Why setting delete cascade on `many-to-many` relation is wrong? Imagine we have such relation between Student and Course. And we have delete cascane in both directions. And now cancelling one course would cause removal from university all students enrolled to this course. Similarilly removal of one student would cause cancelling all courses he was enrolled.

In your code you have deletion cascade in both directions of relation. It turned out that it is too difficult task for Ebean. But suppose that Ebean have done exactly what you have told him. It would be disaster. Why?

1. You are deleting `Issue` with `id=1`
2. Deletion is cascaded to all tags related to this issue.
3. Deletion is cascaded to all issues related to all tags deleted in previous point
4. Go back to 2.

So if all issues and tags are connected in network then deleting one of them would cause deletion of entire network.

If you remove these cascades then your code will work correctly.
Removing issue will cause:

- removing one row from `issue` table
- removing appropriate rows from `issue_tag` table